# Jquery Hide table row on hover

Tags: jquery, hover

I have a div containing li's and a div containing a table. When there is a hover on a li I want the "system" to take the "refSortie" attribute and hide the table rows for which the "refDate" attribute equals the "refSortie" attribute. My code is not working. Hope someone can help. Thank you in advance for your replies. Cheers. Marc.

My HTML :

```
<div id="contentWrapper">
    <div id="contentOne" class="content">
        <ul>
            <li refSortie="mmm">MMMMM</li>
            <li refSortie="sss">SSSSS</li>
            <li refSortie="mmm">MMMMM</li>
            <li refSortie="ppp">PPPPP</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="contentTwo" class="content">
        <table>
            <tr refDate="mmm"><td>MMMMM</td><td>hdqjkhs</td><td>hdqjkhs</td></tr>
            <tr refDate="mmm"><td>MMMMM</td><td>hdqjkhs</td><td>hdqjkhs</td></tr>
            <tr refDate="ppp"><td>PPPPP</td><td>hdqjkhs</td><td>hdqjkhs</td></tr>
            <tr refDate="sss"><td>SSSSS</td><td>hdqjkhs</td><td>hdqjkhs</td></tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div id="contentThree" class="content"></div>
    <div id="contentFour" class="content"></div>
</div>
```

My JS :

```
$('#contentOne li').hover(function(){
    var refSortie=$(this).attr('refSortie');

    if(!$('#contentOne').hasClass('freezed')){
        $('#contentTwo table tr[refDate=refSortie]').css("display":"none");}
}).mouseout(function(){
    if(!$('#contentOne').hasClass('freezed')){
        $('#contentTwo table tr[refDate=refSortie]').css("display":"inline");}    
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a multitude of things going on here.  Fixed js code:
http://jsfiddle.net/brentmn/cRJdz/

```
$('#contentOne li').hover(function() {
    var refSortie = $(this).attr('refSortie');

    if (!$('#contentOne').hasClass('freezed')) {
        $('#contentTwo table tr[refDate!=' + refSortie + ']').css("display", "none");
    }
}).mouseout(function() {
    var refSortie = $(this).attr('refSortie');
    if (!$('#contentOne').hasClass('freezed')) {
        $('#contentTwo table tr').css("display", "inline");
    }
});
```

The errors were:
`refDate=refSortie` //needs to be  variable
`css("display":"inline")`  // if you want to set css this way, you must use an obj e.g. `css({"display": "inline"})`

Answer (score 1):

Fixed a bunch of issues. [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/hKRWQ/1/) here

1. You can use hover for both mouse enter and mouse leave. Read [here](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)
2. The refSortie is a variable and so it has to be appended to the selector as a string. `$('#contentTwo table tr[refDate="' + refSortie +'"]')`
3. `refSortie` not initialized in the mouse out handler.
4. `.css` function takes an associative array (`.css({"color":"red"})` )or a single style separated by comma (`.css("color","red")`).
5. changed `.css({"display","inline"});` to `.css({"display","block"});` because it is a table.

See code below,

```
    $('#contentOne li').hover(function() {
      var refSortie = $(this).attr('refSortie');

      if (!$('#contentOne').hasClass('freezed')) {
        $('#contentTwo table tr[refDate="' + refSortie +'"]').css({"display": "none"});
      }
     }, function() {
        var refSortie = $(this).attr('refSortie');
        if (!$('#contentOne').hasClass('freezed')) {
           $('#contentTwo table tr[refDate="' + refSortie + '"]').css({"display": "block"});
        }
     });
```

Comment: giving you bump as I like you're answer too.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#contentOne li').hover(function(){
    $('#contentTwo tr[refDate='+$(this).attr('refSortie')+']').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your variable is in quotes. Need to concatenate.

```
$('#contentTwo table tr[refDate=' + refSortie + ']')
```